# Vertically align Bootstrap badge inside heading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

When I use a Bootstrap `badge` inside of heading such as `h1`,`h2`,`h3` the vertical alignment is off. The `badge` aligns towards the bottom of the heading text. I'd like the badge to align vertically centered with the heading text.

**HTML**

```
<h1><span class="badge">badge</span> Heading 1</h1>
<hr>
<h2><span class="badge">badge</span> Heading 2</h2>
<hr>
<h3><span class="badge">badge</span> Heading 3</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
h1,h2,h3 {
  vertical-align:middle;
}

h1>.badge, h2>.badge, h3>.badge {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**Result**..

See this Bootply: http://bootply.com/88526

[image]

How can I get this to align on center vertically?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Always hated this problem.

A little hacky but this works:

```
h1 { font-size: 2em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.6em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.4em; }
h1,h2,h3 {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

  h1>.badge, h2>.badge, h3>.badge {
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

Defined the heading font-sizes for demo purposes

Comment: I was able to use a one-liner: `h3>.badge { vertical-align: middle }`

Comment: I didn't need the margin-top (in fact, setting margin-top messed the alignment).

Comment: I didn't need to set the vertical-align on h1, h2, h3 either - just the badge - agree with Brent's comment.

Comment: I needed the margin-top too. Thanks fellas.

Answer (score 7):

In Bootstrap 4, the vertical alignment issue is no longer a problem since the badge will inherit the size of the containing heading..

```
<div class="container">
  <h1><span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">badge</span> Heading 1</h1>
  <hr>
  <h2><span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">badge</span> Heading 2</h2>
  <hr>
  <h3><span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">badge</span> Heading 3</h3>
</div>
```

However, the `align-middle` class be used to vertically align badges outside of the heading.

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark align-middle">badge</span> <span class="h1 align-middle">Heading 1</span>
  <hr>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark align-middle">badge</span> <span class="h2 align-middle">Heading 2</span>
  <hr>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark align-middle">badge</span> <span class="h3 align-middle">Heading 3</span>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/rE0z3665zh