# bootstrap 3 button group in panel-header not centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button group in a panel-header.  I want them floated to the right, but when I do this  the buttons are now down at the bottom of the header and I need them to be centered.  How do I do this?

here's the HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Member of the following Units
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        test
    </div>      
</div>
```

and a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/snowburnt/4ejuK/

Strangely enough, in my linux dev environment on chromium, the buttons themselves are properly centered but the icons within them are lower than they should be, I have a feeling this will answer both these issues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. You should add the class `pull-right` to your .btn-group div, instead of specifying float:right.
2. When you float an element, it loses block layout. It will no longer "push down" the bottom of its container since it doesn't have a height. You can fix this by setting `overflow:hidden` on your `.panel-heading` to allow it to resize properly. You will have to add top padding to the `.panel-heading` and negative top padding to the `.btn-group` to accomodate the height of the `.btn-group.`

I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dq5ge/

Comment: That fixed it for normal browsers, but my linux one still has the icons lower than center...ETA, added nbsp around the button and it started working right.  Great advice though

Answer (score 3):

You must clear your floats. There are many methods for this like the clearfix hack or using overflow: hidden. Which is what i did in your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4ejuK/2/

```
.panel-heading {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

parent elements will collapse if their floated children are not cleared causing a lot of unexpected layout issues.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
.container{
 line-height:2.2;
}
```

along with what David has suggested above to have the text truly in the center vertically.
check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ejuK/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I mixed the 2 best solutions in one, for a better fit without changing too much the size or using top negative index:

```
.panel-heading {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and using:

```
<div class="pull-right">
```

here you are the example: [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xer2rek4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick for that ;)

```
    ...
    Member of the following Units
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="opacity:0.001">I am hidden</div>
    ...
```

Good luck - S.M. Mousavi

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue for myself today. [All of the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836880/bootstrap-3-css-how-to-properly-vertically-align-in-panel-heading) [seemingly-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452111/vertically-align-bootstrap-3-badge-inside-heading) suggestions I found involved setting heights of things in pixels to match the buttons, and that just didn't sit right with me. I wanted the vertical alignment to be independent of the actual height of the panel text itself.

If you look at **[@ithcy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59461/ithcy)**'s answer, and jack up the `font-size`, you have a problem (**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shudnt4m/2/)**).

The more googling I did, the more I became convinced that CSS's `vertical-align` was what I wanted, but it never seemed to do what I think it should do. Then I ran across **[an article by Louis Lazaris](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/)** that better explained what `vertical-align` is,

> The `vertical-align` property can be broken down into three
>   easy-to-understand steps:
>
> 1. It only applies to `inline` or `inline-block` elements
> 2. It affects the
>      alignment of the element itself, not its contents (except when applied
>      to table cells)
> 3. When it’s applied to a table cell, the alignment
>      affects the cell contents, not the cell itself

and more importantly *is **not***:

> The common misconception about `vertical-align` is that, when it’s
>   applied to an element, it will make all the elements inside that
>   element change their vertical position.

My solution was to use CSS table formatting (which is what `vertical-align` is for, after all) instead of the `float`s that Bootstrap provides with `pull-left` and `pull-right`. It takes a little extra markup the way I (naively) did it, but I got the result I wanted:

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-heading table-style">
  <span class="panel-title">Member of...</span>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel-heading.table-style {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel-heading.table-style .panel-title {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}
.panel-heading.table-style .button-wrap {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}
```

I made a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shudnt4m/4/)** of the way I'm using it, which I'm sure can be improved on.

*I am very aware that the `btn-group` has a tendency to wrap with this method, which looks terrible. I just don't have the knowledge or experience to fix it. In my use case, I only need single buttons, not groups, so it's working well enough for me.*

Answer (score 0):

It's very late, but I simply solve by this css:

```
.panel-heading h3,
.panel-heading .btn-group
{
  display:inline-block;
}
```