# Bootstrap 3 / CSS: How to properly vertically align in panel heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I use Bootstrap 3 to create panels with a structure like the below and would like to vertically align the span within the panel heading and without extending the default height of the panel heading.

I tried different approaches (adding `class="clearfix"`, adding `style="vertical-align:middle !important;"` adding `style="overflow:hidden !important;"` etc.) but they are all either ignored or they increase the default height of the panel heading.

My guess is that this is due to the "pull-right" class but as this is an official Bootstrap class I hope there is some workaround for this.

How can I achieve this? (The image I use within the link is only 32x32 so its height is less than the height of the panel heading.)

**Example panel:**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Categories
        <span class="pull-right"><a href="#"><img src='images/icons/myImage.png' alt='' /></a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        // ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a clearfix class on the panel-heading: http://jsbin.com/yowis/1/edit

Comment: To make them both align, put a clearfix on the wrapper AND add some css to match the height: http://jsbin.com/yowis/2/edit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/yowis/2/edit

```
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
```

This will clear the float issue. That's what the issue is.

If you want both the text and the image:

```
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
```

and the CSS is:

```
.panel-heading {line-height:32px;}
```

If you don't want to add clearfix, put this anywhere in your css:

```
.panel-heading:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.panel-heading:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this "vertical-align: middle" version of your jsbin doesn't align to the center? http://jsbin.com/mumatapeca/edit?html,css,js,output  Many thanks!

Comment: Veritical align middle works with inline, inline-block, and table/table cell situations, not floats.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Just change the img src to http://placehold.it/164x164

Answer (score 0):

I have a working fiddle of this and can't find your issue.
Could you look over this and check the result is what you intended please.

I've only copied out the code from Bootstrap documentation in order to get this far, but am struggling to see if the issue is resolved as I'm not sure how to replicate your problem.

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/showcaseimagery/jbvbojy0/

**html**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Categories
        <span class="pull-right"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/32x32"></a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        this is panel body
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
 img {
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    margin-top:-7px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks - The HTML is correct but the fiddle doesn't showw any Bootstrap formatting for me.

Comment: hey @tom thats because there was nothing to add. the image aligns vertical centre already.

Comment: ok tom, i added a background color to highlight the offset. since that i can see that it wasn't aligned.

Comment: You just add a clearfix on the .panel-heading and that is it. See my comments.