# fixed top header to show on top of div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This code uses and bootstrap 3.

How can I get the span with class="badge" to vertically line up with the left cell content i.e. baseline with the menuItem?  (I tried some text alignment for no avail )  Thank you

[image]

```css
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
//---main.html-------------------------------
<head>
  <title>Tasks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <header class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h1>
            <button class="col-xs-2" type="button">&#9776;</button>
            <label class="col-xs-8 text-center">Select item</label>
            <button class="col-xs-2" type="button">&#8942;</button>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </header>
    </nav>
  </header>


  <div>
    {{> mainMenu}}
  </div>
</body>

//---main_menu.html-------------------------------
<template name="mainMenu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="list-group">
          {{#each menuItems}}
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
              <img src="/abc.png">
              {{menuItem}}  <span class="badge">&#x3e;</span>
            </a>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `list-group-item`s are fixed height the simplest way to handle this is margin css.

```
.list-item-group > span.badge {
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Other vertical align tricks such as `line-height` don't work on badges because they already have specific styles.

Here is another possible related solution:

[Vertically align Bootstrap 3 badge inside heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452111/vertically-align-bootstrap-3-badge-inside-heading)

Note: Your question does not actually relate to Meteor, you might have better luck getting answers if you remove the meteor templating from your snippet.