# Middle align inline code inside h2 tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this example ([bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/hWcimJnDuq#)):

`<h2>Title <small><code>one line</code></small></h2>`

I am trying to middle align the code element with the title. I tried to use `vertical-align: middle` for the code element (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452111/vertically-align-bootstrap-3-badge-inside-heading)), however it doesn't do what I want. Is there any way to put code element higher?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's a couple problems with your css. First, you're selecting a class `.code` and not the element (no `.code` class exists). Secondly, your `>` selector won't work since `code` isn't a direct child of `h2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
small {
  padding: 0 .25em;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title <small><code>one line</code></small></h2>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately, Twitter Bootstrap puts a box around the code line (see the link that I gave). Which is then misaligned with the title. That is, the title and the text of the code are aligned (bottom), but I would better prefer the code's box to be aligned in the middle of title. Is there any way you can help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what *box* you are referring to...there doesn't seem to be one in the link you provided. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YqQMZb

Comment: Strange but it behaves differently on bootply http://www.bootply.com/iGJqxVx1jK. When referring to box I meant the red wrapping around code.