# Bootstrap Label not centered vertically with text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to vertically align a label with a h3 element, but the label is not centered vertically. It is to low.

```
<h3>Text <span class="label label-danger">Label</span></h3>
```

Comment: remove margin-top of H3 tag

Comment: There's a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452111/vertically-align-bootstrap-3-badge-inside-heading

Comment: @YanetPedraza That worked! :D